# Linker command failed with exit code architecture i386 xcode

Tags: facebook, sqlite, xcode7, google-signin, ios-frameworks

I have an app that I am using various other Frameworks and libraries in.

FacebookSDK, GoogleSignIn, libsqlite3

I have included these in my  buildSettings and even put Facebook in my Frameworks path and libxml2 in the Header Search Path.

However when I build in the simulator I get 21 errors which say 
"linker command failed with exit code 1 
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

this only happens with the simulator not on any device.

I am attaching a screen shot.[image]

Any ideas would help.  I have look at a lot of questions with this with no solution.

Answer (score 0):

The lines in yellow are telling you the problem. When you compile for the simulator you are producing i386 code, for a real device you are producing ARM code. The libraries you are using do not contain i386 code, hence the errors.

You need to obtain versions of the libraries with i386 code.

HTH